# Where can I find an example of using the ant colony optimisation method for the knapsack problem?

Tags: reference-request, optimization, np-complete, packing-problem

I could not find any examples of solving the knapsack problem using ant colony optimisation (have only found the description of a method). Does anyone have links to resources for this?

Comment: How about https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjn95PMloDbAhXRwFkKHaDABpYQFgg5MAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fsuw.biblos.pk.edu.pl%2FdownloadResource%26mId%3D1139440&usg=AOvVaw1-cNRPewkYsYuaKQT-5hnE ?

Comment: @MarkL.Stone thanks for the link :) do you think you could pull this out into an answer, perhaps with a high-level overview of how ACO is applied to the problem?

Comment: @GuiltyDolphin No, I found this by googling. I don't know much about ant colony optimization, but what little I do know does not leave me with a favorable opinion, and that's all I 'll say on the subject.